# Multiple location on vhost nginx to redirect to too proxy pass

Tags: node.js, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location, proxypass

I'm new on stackoverflow. I have a serious problem at work.
I have too nextjs app running under docker and i use nginx as a reverse proxy to have app1.com and app2.com. It's work perfectly like that.

I want to do something like app1.com/app2 with my configuration below and it work but all js,css,png file is under 404 on browser console. (Get https://app1.com/_next/image?url=%2F_next%2Fstatic%2Fmedia%image.4311b395.png 404) Here is the error.

Can you help me please guys? Thanks in advance.

Here are my vhost configuration (Sorry if the format is not correct, please tell me and i'll correct):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name app1.com;

    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/wildcard.app1.com_2023-03-13.key;

    server_name app1.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/app1.com.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/app1.com.error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9700;
        #proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        #proxy_set_header Host $host;
        #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /backoffice/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000/;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    }
}
```